# In case of Python KeyError, how to return a value of None if a key does't exist

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror, yfinance

In my case, I have an empty dictionary which I want to fill with Key:Value pairs about stock tickers information. I tested the code below but I always get a KeyError message whenever a key is missing from the list of tickers I loop through. All I want is to set a group of default Keys for all my tickers (Info_data in the code below), then set the value of the missing "Key" to "None" whenever it finds a missing key.

Here is my code:

```
stocks_info = {}
for symbol in tqdm(sav_set):
    info = yf.Tickers(symbol).tickers[symbol].info
    if info['quoteType'] == 'EQUITY':
        info_data = {'symbol': symbol, 'shortName': info['shortName'], 'country': info['country'],
                     'sector': info['sector'], 'industry': info['industry'], 'marketCap': info['marketCap'],
                     'currentPrice': info['currentPrice'], 'quoteType': info['quoteType'], 'market': info['market']}
```

Comment: `dict.get(key_you_seek, default)` Use `None` as the default.

Comment: I have more than one key as in the example. Will this method accept more than one key? or do I have to repeat it for each key I want?

Comment: You would use `dict.get(key, default)` in the same way you are using `dict[key]`.

Comment: still can't get it to work, sorry this could be me since I am relatively new to python.

Comment: Make a simpler version work first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @dawg for providing help. This is how I managed to resolve my issue:

```
stocks_info = {}
for symbol in tqdm(sav_set):
    info = yf.Tickers(symbol).tickers[symbol].info
    # info_keys = {'symbol', 'shortName', 'longName', 'country', 'sector', 'industry', 'marketCap', 'currentPrice',
    #              'navPrice', 'quoteType', 'market'}

    ticker = info.get('symbol', None)
    shortName = info.get('shortName', None)
    longName = info.get('longName', None)
    country = info.get('country', None)
    sector = info.get('sector', None)
    industry = info.get('industry', None)
    marketCap = info.get('marketCap', None)
    currentPrice = info.get('currentPrice', None)
    navPrice = info.get('navPrice', None)
    quoteType = info.get('quoteType', None)
    market = info.get('market', None)

    if info['quoteType'] == 'EQUITY':
        info_data = {'symbol': ticker, 'shortName': shortName, 'longName': longName, 'country': country,
                     'sector': sector, 'industry': industry, 'marketCap': marketCap, 'currentPrice': currentPrice,
                     'quoteType': quoteType, 'market': market}
    else:
        info_data = {'symbol': ticker, 'shortName': shortName, 'longName': longName, 'country': country,
                     'sector': sector, 'industry': industry, 'marketCap': marketCap, 'currentPrice': navPrice,
                     'quoteType': quoteType, 'market': market}

    stocks_info[symbol] = info_data
    json_object = json.dumps(stocks_info)
    with open("../tickers_data/stocks_info.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```